# My R-Studio environment doesn't appear(won't work) when opening

Tags: r, console, rstudio

These days, when I try opening my R-Studio, the application does not show anything on my screen. I can only see the app icon in the app bar.
[problemImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R3v9.jpg)

I have tried uninstalled R & R-Studio and re-installed them(R 1st. and R-Studio then), but nothing is changed. I'm quite sure my R software works but the R-Studio doesn't work.

R-Studio version: 1.2.1335(lateset one)

R version: 3.3.3(I was required to use this version)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try following option for your observation.

1. Delete temporary file.
2. Increase RAM size up 16 GB.
3. Restart system.

else download Anaconda and get all tools easily.

Regards
Tushar

Comment: Thanks for informing me to delete all temporary files.
However, I don't understand how to increase my RAM to 16 GB when my laptop is currently 8 GB.